# Kinda newbie: PowerApps to populate a list with constructed data fields

Tags: list, tracking, powerapps, sequential, forall

Updated...

Trying to inject a series of rows into a SharePoint List via PowerApps, but running across  the fact that PowerApps seems to only have FORALL as a looping function, and that does not support SET.

```
   Set(AlertString,""); // to be used later
   Set(REQ_Value,"");
   Set(RITM_Value,"");
   Set(Asset_Value,"");
   Set(CustomerSignatureFileLocation_Value,"File location: ");
   Set(LoanerKitCode_Value,"");
   Set(IncidentCode_Value,"");
   Set(TransferOrderCode_Value,"");
   Set(TransactionType_Value,Workflow.SelectedText.Value & " - " & Workflow_Steps.SelectedText.Value);
   Set(ScanItemCodeType,"");
   Set(ErrorString,"");
   Collect(ScanDataCollection,Split(ScanData.Text,Char(10))); // Split the data into ScanDataCollection collection
   ForAll(
       ScanDataCollection,
       If(Left(Result,4)="RITM",Set(RITM_Value,Result); // FAIL HERE
       Collect('Spider - Master Transaction List', {
           REQ: REQ_Value,
           RITM: RITM_Value,
           Scan_Code: Result,
           Asset: Asset_Value,
           Transaction_Type: TransactionType_Value,
           Timestamp: Now(),
           Agent_Name: User().FullName,
           Agent_Email: User().Email,
           Agent_Location: DD_Location.SelectedText.Value,
           Agent_Notes: "It was weird, man.",
           Customer_Name: Cust_Name.Text,
           Customer_Email: Cust_NTAccount.Text,
           Customer_Signature: CustomerSignatureFileLocation_Value,
           Task_Name: "",
           Task_Action: "",
           State_Name: "",
           State_Action: "",
           Stage_Name: "",
           Stage_Action: "",
           Work_Note_String: "",
           Customer_Note_String: "",
           Loaner_Kit_Code: LoanerKitCode_Value,
           Incident: IncidentCode_Value,
           Transfer_Order_Code: TransferOrderCode_Value,
           Item_Description: ""});
   );
```

My scanner tool will pick up a variety of different kinds of item scans, all in the same scan. Depending on what type of data it is, it populates different columns in Spider - Master Transaction List.

But we are forbidden to use the SET function inside a FORALL.

How would you recommend I approach this -- considering that each piece of data from the SPLIT could be any of the sorts of codes (such as RITM Code, REQ Code, Transfer Order Code, etc.)?

Comment: This is a very weird problem statement/question.  Where does your data come from? What is the format of the data? You talk about arrays, loops and whether or not PowerApps has them, but you don't describe your data source. Let's start a bit smaller. What is your input? What is your desired output? Simplify that if it's too complex. What is the processing logic that leads from input to output. And why would you use PowerApps to do that?

Comment: Data source: “My app automatically knows the Agent name and Agent Email (because of system variables). My app collects the Location, Workflow, and Workflow Step (Workflow + Workflow Step = Process) via drop-downs. The Item list is collected as part of a bar code scan, and all the Items appear in a multiline text window. Could be as many as a hundred or more Items in a scan (for such things as an inventory).”

Comment: Desired output: “ I want to shovel all this data into a single big Sharepoint Master List. That List has several columns, including Agent Name, Agent Email, Location, Item, Timestamp, Process, etc. Each row is a Item Transaction, basically Item has been touched at Location on Timestamp by Agent for Process reason. That Master List will eventually have a few hundred thousand rows or more to it. Yes, it'll go slow, but not as slow as what we have now.”

Comment: “What is the processing logic that leads from input to output.” I tried guessing using pseudocode above. What form would you prefer?

Comment: “And why would you use PowerApps to do that?” It is the tool I am allowed to use. I am not allowed to stand up a server/internal website, nor can I build a system “outside the fence” because some of this is specific employee data that is not allowed “outside.” Otherwise, I would simply bulls this as a db-backed website.

Comment: Format of data: typically strings. The Items that I am tracking will be only certain kinds of formatted strings, but I left out data validation from my pseudocode above for purposes of clarity. Ultimately, each Item is of a PackageType, which is how I determine how to handle the data. For example if PackageType = “TrackingCode,” then I insert it into the Tracking Code field, but if the PackageType is an Asset Tag, then that datum is inserted into the Asset Tag field. The Master Transactions list has a LOT of fields.

Comment: Also, I think very weirdly. :) This app is replacing a tool that currently exists in our Production space. The current tool is a VBA tool (which I wrote) operating under Excel, but although it’s been operating almost three years, it has some deeply impractical aspects.

Comment: “And why would you use PowerApps to do that?” oh, also because the existing system is in VBA running under Excel, and as such it only runs on Windows platforms. Our environment contains a variety of platforms. A Powerapps canvas app runs on an iphone, which allows the camera to be used to collect scan data. We have 20-50 techs in the field collecting data all day, so a web-app front end onto something that at least acts SOMEWHAT like a database is better than an Excel VBA app. Also, the interface has to be super-duper simple on the user side.

Comment: Can you PLEASE take the [tour] and learn how this site works? Then update you question with the details. Nobody will read through a wall of comments to figure out what you're really asking. And, don't throw everything into one question. The answer should fit on a page, not be a whole book.

Comment: I answered each of the questions you asked as completely as I could (often quoting from the original post, ahem), and I literally did update the original question. If you are not interested in following, I think you can unsub from this discussion. But berating me for answering the questions you asked seems... to use your phrasing... weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that you want on various way.

Using Collection or Gallery, in powrapps Galleries can be used like a collection.

I Suggest:

```
ForAll(
  Gallery.Allitems, 
  Patch(
   'SharepointListName',      
   ThisRecord
  )
);
```

Fields in gallery must have the same name of sharepoint list, or you have to create a record to asign the names.

```
{sharepoitColumnName: ThisRecord.ColumnName, ...}
```

Comment: Oh, I am unfamiliar with “gallery.” I will search on that now. But for your example, ThisRecord would not simply be the result of the Split, but a composite record that included one of the items from the Split.

Comment: Okay, I understand better now. From what I can tell, I would use a gallery to display results from a specific search. that eventually becomes a thing I will need to do, but I have to get the data-input section right, first.

Comment: Ah, I see something else -- in my case, PATCH and COLLECT are basically the same function. Would PATCH allow me to build all those elements and then add the entire set of records? In your example you are nesting a PATCH within a FORALL. I would need to build a new record for each item and then inject them one at a time? That feels like a more traditional programing solution.

Comment: Collect ad data to a Collection, Patch do this and more. Patch is used for create, update (with condiction, be carefull and combined with the RenameColumn function is very usefull). I can say Path is the all in one on powerapps. About Galleries so is a all in one too, each component inside it is like a variable, and each row is a record of a itself collection. You can iterate over galleries with ForAll, Concat, etc

Comment: Okay, starting from here, and combined with tweaking my expectations of how data will be stored in the List, I settled on using Collection. These are audit trails, so I want no potential for changing old data. But your response got me rolling in the right direction, so thank you!